# How to get the repeater-item in a Checkbox' CheckedChanged-event?

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, repeater

I have a `CheckBox` inside a `Repeater`. Like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEvaluationInfo" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label runat="server" Id="lblCampCode" Text="<%#Eval("CampCode") %>"></asp:Label>
       <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbCoaching" value="coaching-required" ClientIDMode="AutoID" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="cbCoaching_OnCheckedChanged" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

When some one clicks on the `checkbox` I want to get that entire row in my code behind. So if  a `CheckedChanged` happens I want to get the `Text` of the `Label` `lblCampCode` in code behind.

Is it possible?

I have managed to write this much code.

```
protected void cbCoaching_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    Repeater rpt = (Repeater)chk.Parent.Parent;
    string CampCode = "";//  here i want to get the value of CampCode in that row
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So you want to get the `RepeaterItem`? You do that by casting the `NamingContainer` of the `CheckBox`(the sender argument). Then you're almost there, you need [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) for the label:

```
protected void cbCoaching_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem) chk.NamingContainer;
    Label lblCampCode = (Label) item.FindControl("lblCampCode");
    string CampCode = lblCampCode.Text;//  here i want to get the value of CampCode in that row
}
```

This has the big advantage over `Parent.Parent`-approaches that it works even if you add other container controls like `Panel` or `Table`.

By the way, this works the similar way for  any databound web-control in ASP.NET (like `GridView` etc).