# Asp.net/C# Get repeater row data through checkbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, repeater

Hello i have a repeater that will present data as a table with checkbox for each row, so i want to show the checked rows data when a button is clicked.

.aspx code:

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table-striped table-condensed">
                <tr>
                    <th> </th>
                    <th>Goods Desc</th>
                    <th>Balance Units</th>
                    <th>Exit Units</th>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:CheckBox ID="cbItem" runat="server" /></td>                    
                <td><%#Eval("ItemDesc") %></td>
                <td><%#Eval("InvoicBalanceUnits") %></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtExitUnits" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revUnits" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtExitUnits" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ErrorMessage="Please, insert a number." CssClass="text-danger"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUnits" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtExitUnits" ErrorMessage="Insert number of units." CssClass="text-danger"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>      
            </tr>             
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
              </table>   
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

the code behind:

```
protected void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
        List<RepeaterItem> selectedItems = rptItems.Items.Cast<RepeaterItem>().Where(x => ((CheckBox)x.FindControl("cbItem")).Checked).ToList();

        Repeater1.DataSource = selectedItems;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

Repeater1 will contain the data selected through :`selectedItems` 
this is the repeater1

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table-striped table-condensed">
            <tr>                    
                <th>Goods Desc</th>
                <th>Balance Units</th>                    
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>                
            <td><%#Eval("ItemDesc") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("InvoicBalanceUnits") %></td>         
        </tr>         
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
          </table>   
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

when i run the code it gives me an error that "ItemDesc" isn't exist in repeater1, whats wrong ?

Comment: @Phill what's wrong with this, or there's another solution ?

Comment: @Phill so all exisiting Web Forms projects should be deleted? hilarious comment

Comment: You cannot bind List<RepeaterItem> to Repeater1 as you are trying to do. RepeaterItem class doesn't have ItemDesc property. On button click create same type of collection that you have as data source for rptItems, an then it will work.

Comment: How to specify the selected checkbox rows in repeater:rptItems @j.v.

Comment: Solved by reference to this article: [How to get the repeater-item in a Checkbox' CheckedChanged-event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308247/how-to-get-the-repeater-item-in-a-checkbox-checkedchanged-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by reference to this:

```
 DataTable checkedData = new DataTable();
    checkedData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[6] { new DataColumn("CampCode"), new DataColumn("BalUnits", typeof(decimal)), new DataColumn("ExitUni",typeof(decimal)), new DataColumn("itemNum"), new DataColumn("UOM"), new DataColumn("WT", typeof(decimal)) });
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptItems.Items)
    {
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            CheckBox checkBoxInRepeater = item.FindControl("cbItem") as CheckBox;

            if (checkBoxInRepeater.Checked)
            {
                DataRow dr = checkedData.NewRow();
                Label lblCampCode = (Label)item.FindControl("lblCampCode");
                Label lblBalUnits = (Label)item.FindControl("lblBalUnits");
                TextBox txtExitUnits = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtExitUnits");
                Label lblItemNo = (Label)item.FindControl("lblItemNo");
                Label lblUom = (Label)item.FindControl("lblUom");
                Label lblWT =  (Label)item.FindControl("lblWt");
                Label lblcode = (Label)item.FindControl("lblCode");
                HiddenField hfcode = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("hfCustomerId");

                string BalUnits = lblBalUnits.Text;
                string ExitUni = txtExitUnits.Text;

                var exitUni = decimal.Parse(txtExitUnits.Text);
                var balUni = decimal.Parse(BalUnits);



                if (exitUni > balUni)
                {
                  string myStringVariable = "Exit balance is larger than balance units!!";
                  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + myStringVariable + "');", true);
                }
                else
                { 

                    dr["CampCode"] = lblCampCode.Text;
                    dr["BalUnits"] = lblBalUnits.Text;
                    dr["itemNum"] =  lblItemNo.Text;
                    dr["UOM"] = lblUom.Text;
                    dr["WT"] = lblWT.Text;
                    dr["ExitUni"] = txtExitUnits.Text.Trim();

                    //string code = hfcode.Value;
                    checkedData.Rows.Add(dr);
                    Session["CheckedRows"] = checkedData;
```